# Defining model properties in JavaScript - is there a need

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a Node.js API and i keep changing my mind with regards to defining properties for my models or not.

Coming from .Net and c# i am used to defining the properties of a class but as that is as statically defined language that makes sense.  With javascript being so dynamic it feels a little dirty and i really am not sure why.

It's been a long week so i may be just complicating things and should continue but any insight would be great.

**Simple example with some properties**

```
var Post = exports = module.exports = function(postData){
    var post = postData || {};

    //Set Properties
    this.id = post.id || 0;
    this.message = post.message || '';
};
```

Comment: Why do your properties have defaults? That seems like bad API design. If you don't specify an `id` can you still specify a `message`? Likewise, if `postData` is not an object just throw an Error, immediately.

Comment: It depends, i may create a new post and attempt to save.  A new post wouldn't have an id but you would be able to specify a message in that instance.  Second point, you are right, that is a much better option.  I usually let this stuff fall out the bottom of itself and if it smells gets changed, i just chucked something out there to push the point, its not really an API design question.

Comment: the code seems ok to me if `id` and `message` are public properties and you specify in your docs how to use the function (if it's a public function used by others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have some form of schema, then how do you plan to read the data?

If you're planning to put data in a Database and then actually read that data back out, you need a schema. Even with the fancy "schema-less" NoSQL database, you still need some way of understanding the data that comes back "schema-less" != "schema-free".

If you look at the various Javascript DB frameworks, there are lots of wrappers that enforce some kind of schema: Mongoose for MongoDB, Geddy JS has a universal "[Model](http://geddyjs.org/documentation#models)" type. Even without static typing you want some form of tool to know what's in the object you're getting back.

> i keep changing my mind with regards to defining properties for my models

C# has a very specific definition of "property". In that sense, you probably don't want "properties", but you probably *do* want "fields".

> With javascript being so dynamic it feels a little dirty and i really am not sure why.

As a user with an MS background, you may want to consider Microsoft's [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). It actually has an NPM package and provides basic typing that will compile into regular Javascript.

Comment: It was the end of a long week and i think i just started to brain dump out.  I think what was in my head was the notion of being very dynamic  but when i came back to it fresh i was under the same impression as you as my API would have stunk worse then week old socks.  I can accept this as the answer but would ask that you remove the TypeScript stuff.  I am going through the process of learning JS again properly, things like TypeScript and CoffeeScript are not going to help me (or anyone wanting to learn fully) do that.  I will mess up, but i will also learn JS better from that.

Comment: Just want to add, that there is nothing with these superset languages, i am working to understand the base JS language much better then i did, so when i do come to use CoffeeScript for example i will appreciate the full scope of the language, warts and all.